# No peer certificate error on android 2.3 devices but working fine on android 4+

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

1. I have created the bks file for my server's certificate. This was added in the project's sources in raw folder
2. I've created my https client as follows:

   public class MyHttpsClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

   ```
   final Context context;

   public MyHttpsClient(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
       SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
       registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
       // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
       // to the ConnectionManager
       registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
       return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
   }

   private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
       try {
           // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
           KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
           // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
           // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
           InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykeystore);
           try {
               // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
               // Also provide the password of the keystore
               trusted.load(in, "testpassword".toCharArray());
           } finally {
               in.close();
           }
           // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
           // for the verification of the server certificate.
           SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
           // Hostname verification from certificate
           // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
           sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
           return sf;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AssertionError(e);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Then I use it like:

   ```
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new MyHttpsClient(context);
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 30000);
   HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
   httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString));

   response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   httpresponse = getResponse(entity);
   ```
4. Now here comes the funny part. This works just fine on android 4+ both real devices and emulator. THIS fails on android 2.3 with

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

How can I make it work on android 2.3 without the known "trust all certificates" way ?

Answer (score 0):

A few days age i solved same problem. The solution consisted in the following. I take all certificates installed on device(in my case it was samsung galaxy II) and go to the server side developer, who manage certificate chain installed on server. He analyzes ssl chain and detected that in chain there is one certificate (Thawte 2006) and other certificate (Thawte 2010). He removed oldest certificate, which issued in 2006, and ssl verification on android 2.x become working. I suggest you, before trying to get work local keystore, research your server side ssl chain and check that this chain doesn't have unnecessary certificates, because android 2.x devices cannot ignore not necessary certificates, but other platforms 3.x 4x and ios, windows phone can do it, i mean ignore "trash" in ssl certificate chain.